# Open and half-closed line ranges in awk

Tags: awk

`/begpat/, /endpat/ { action }` in awk effectively corresponds to a closed line interval (both ends included) -- in mathematical notation `[begpat, endpath]`.

What are standard awk ways of matching open line intervals (`(begpat, endpat)`) and half-closed line intervals (`(begpat, endpat]`, `[begpat,endpat)`)?

**Example:**

```
 printf '%s\n' 0 1 2 3 4 5 | awk '/1/,/4/ { print $0 }' #prints 1 through 4 ([1,4])
```

What is a standard awk way of making it print intervals `(1,4)` (= `[2,3]`),
`(1,4]` (=`[2,4]`), and `[1,4)` (=`[1,3]`) without changing the endpoint patterns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "standard" way. You have to implement it, for example, set flag variables. After checking your stackoverflow profile, I think you know how to do it.

an example for `(start,end)` case:

```
/start/{doIt=1;next}/end/{doIt=0}doIt{doActionhere}.
```

`[..), (..]` would be pretty similar.

### update

since you gave example, I append codes for your example: (all examples assume the start & end patterns are different.)

#### [1,4]

```
kent$  seq 0 5|awk '/1/,/4/'
1
2
3
4
```

#### (1,4)

```
kent$  seq 0 5|awk '/1/{f=1;next}/4/{f=0}f'  
2
3
```

#### (1,4]

```
kent$  seq 0 5|awk '/1/{f=1;next}f;/4/{f=0}'    
2
3
4
```

#### [1,4)

```
kent$  seq 0 5|awk '/1/{f=1}/4/{f=0}f'
1
2
3
```

Comment: Thanks. You can't spell awkward without awk, I guess.

Comment: @PSkocik I have this in a function in my startup script: `awk 'BEGIN{print ARGV[0]ARGV[1]}' ward`